# How to store "multiple 2-dimensional arrays" in a single file using Java?

Tags: java, file, neural-network

I'm working on a neural network in Java. This is my first project on neural networks so I don't know much about it. Now when I train my network the weights of the network will only be available for that execution only. It is general that we should store all the weights in a file (generally csv file). But my problem here is my model contains many layers of network. It is really difficult to store all the weights between each layer in different files.

So I want to know
**is there a technique that I can store all the weights in only one file?**

It directly means that **is there any way that I can store multiple 2-dimensional arrays in the same file?**

Comment: Try to check this thread: [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958829/how-to-save-a-2d-array-into-a-text-file-with-bufferedwriter)! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for helping. But i want to store **multiple 2d arrays** in a single file.

Comment: If you know how to store an array - "multiple 2-dimensional arrays" can just be stored as 3-dimensional array.

Comment: Three dimensional  array isnt just possible in a two dimensional text file.

Comment: I think is works so **please give the same  above comment as an answer so that I can accept it**